# Errors running Visual Web Developer 2008 Express

Tags: c#, asp.net-3.5

I downloaded the free Visual Web Developer 2008 Express for my Windows XP machine and when I make a new Web Site, with no code of my own yet added, it fails to run, first saying that it isn't configured for ASP.Net 2.0 and that I must do it myself, and then, when trying to run it anyway I get the error "Unable to start debugging on the webserver.  The underlying connection was closed.  The connection was closed unexpectedly."
     What kind of configuration am I missing (and how do I do it??)
     Thanks,
          bsperlin

Answer (score 1):

Did you install IIS *after* installing .net?

Try running the [asp.net regiis](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h%28VS.80%29.aspx) tool. In a Visual Studio command prompt:

```
aspnet_regiis -u
aspnet_regiis -i
```

Comment: I couldn't find the command prompt in Web Developer (though I've seen it in other VS products) and the program "aspnet_regiis" is not recognized in a normal command prompt.  I did put IIS on the system after the web developer so I went to the "add/remove programs" and removed web developer, then reloaded it from the net.
I can believe that this sequence contributed to my problems.  Was there something I didn't do?

Comment: `aspnet_regiis` is a program in your .net framework folder, typically `c:\<WinInstallDir>\Framework\v2.0.50727` - you can run it from there via a normal command prompt. When the framework installs, it registers with IIS, if it exists. Since you installed IIS after the framework, this step didn't happen.

Comment: Well, the uninstall and reinstall worked as you and Tom said, but the same error comes up.  In addition to the above error, if I run the program without debugging then I get the following error on a webpage:
XML Parsing Error: no element found
Location: http://localhost/BTS3/Default.aspx
Line Number 1, Column 1:

Since IIS is now installed, do I have to remove and then reinstall the Web Developer?  I'm on dialup and that takes many hours to reload (the setup is already on my desktop but it calls for a lot of files from the net).

Comment: You don't need to reinstall Web Developer but you might want to try reinstalling the .net framework. Usually though, running aspnet_regiis fixes it. You can download the framework at http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=0856eacb-4362-4b0d-8edd-aab15c5e04f5&displaylang=en

Answer (score 0):

The first thing - are you running XP Home edition? Since you did not specify either Home or Professional, if you are, they do not have IIS installed nor does it come with XP Home, you could try Cassini web server which can be found [here](http://www.ultidev.com/products/Cassini/).

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: I'm using XP Professional 2002 SP 3.  I got it from a local shop about 1 1/2 years ago but didn't get the disk with it.  I went back this month and they gave me a disk, I installed IIS with it, then removed the Web Developer, redownloaded it and installed it.

Comment: Sounds like something is amiss...you can confirm yourself by going to http://localhost on your browser to see if the IIS is indeed installed. If it is, it could be that you need to register the ASP.NET service...click on Start, Click on Run, enter 'cmd' without quotes, and enter the command that Winston suggested.